# How to prompt iOS user for geoLocation service permission in Ionic

Tags: typescript, firebase, cordova, geolocation, ionic4

I've created a social media app that uses geoLocation services.  It's an Ionic 4 app with a Firebase backend.  GeoLocation services are working with Android but with iOS it's not prompting users for geoLocation access.

I've been looking but can't find an example of how to prompt users for GeoLocation service permission on Platform ready.

Any example on how to check for location services permissions and then prompt a user for location services permissions would be greatly appreciated.

And I assume this would be added to the app.component.ts file.

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to prompt for permission until you request a location. When you ask for a location the first time the permissions system prompt will be displayed.

If you want to check the permission status for Geolocation at any time you can use the 
[cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) plugin (there is an [Ionic wrapper](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/diagnostic)).

Once installed you can enquire about permissions, status, etc.:

```
this.diagnostic.isLocationAvailable(); // returns a promise
this.diagnostic.isLocationAuthorized(); // returns a promise
// etc.
```

Comment: If it's not authorized is there anything you can do to prompt for authorization?  We're not even getting the prompt in iOS

Comment: There is a `requestLocationAuthorization()` method. Check out the [documentation](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#requestlocationauthorization)

Comment: @Sébastien Just tried. That function will be triggered but won't pop up a dialog asking for updating the permission if the user has refused at least once. Is there any way viable to ask again?

Answer (score 0):

You can open your project inside xCode and then click on you project solution then click Info and add the privacy permission “Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description”

This was taken from the following forum post

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/geolocation-permissions/145727/3